# Can't compile code for greatest common divisor?

Tags: java, eclipse, greatest-common-divisor

I am having trouble compiling my code, specifically in the main program where I call "gcd();" What should I be putting in the parentheses? Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class gcd {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        gcd();
    }

    public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the number 1 & 2: ");
        a = console.nextInt();
        b = console.nextInt();
        if (b == 0) 
            return a;
        else return (gcd (b, a % b));
    }
}
```

Comment: "I am having trouble compiling my code" - erm, you're supposed to know that! ... You appear to have code in the wrong place. A recursive call to gcd needs a starting point, right?

Comment: "What should I be putting in the parentheses?" 111 and 259, of course :)

Answer (score 4):

Your `gcd` method takes two integer arguments, so `gcd()` will not compile. I think what you should do here is separate the IO and the calculations - maybe move the IO to the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the number 1 & 2: ");
    int a = console.nextInt();
    int b = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println(gcd(a, b));  // notice the two int arguments
}

public static int gcd(int a, int b) {  // no IO, only gcd calculation
    if (b == 0) 
        return a;
    else return (gcd(b, a % b));
}
```

It's generally good to separate your program into "logical" components. In what I have above, the `main` method handles IO and `gcd` handles the actual computations.

Answer (score 2):

The parentheses allow you to pass data to the method. In this case, you pass two `int`s to `gdc` (`a` and `b`).

When you define your method, the part in between the parentheses and after `public static int gcd` is where you tell your method what variables should be passed to it.

Answer (score 2):

Because the gcd method has two integer values it is receiving (a and b), you should call the method by passing it two integer values. 
For example:`gcd(3, 5);`
Or you can pass two variables of int type.